# My Image slideshow is working fine locally until I upload it onto go daddy hosted server

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow, web-hosting

My Image slideshow I created in JavaScript works fine locally until I upload it online on hosted Server. I am using GoDaddy.

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000);

}
```

```html
<img class="mySlides" src="images/Carizmafront.jpg" alt="Carizma shop front">
<img class="mySlides" src="images/Carizmafront2.jpg" alt= "Carizma inside">
<img class="mySlides" src="images/Carizmafront3.jpg" alt= "Carizma inside">
<img class="mySlides" src="images/Carizmafront4.jpg" alt= "Carizma inside">
```

Comment: Do you have any js errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

use full path for images (http://domain.com/dir/dir2/image.jpg) instead local path (images/Carizmafront.jpg), if works, then you have to find the correct local path